# Incorporating html tags in shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to paste html tags in shiny dashboard but looks like it is not rendering . But the same html tags when tried in w3schools, it is working well. But it is not rendering in shiny. Basically i need to have a dot plot in shiny dashboard

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("graph1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$graph1 <- renderUI({
    HTML('<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>

<script>
var xyValues = [
  {x:50, y:7},
  {x:60, y:8},
  {x:70, y:8},
  {x:80, y:9},
  {x:90, y:9},
  {x:100, y:9},
  {x:110, y:10},
  {x:120, y:11},
  {x:130, y:14},
  {x:140, y:14},
  {x:150, y:15}
];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:160}}],
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `renderFunction` is not taking any dependencies. Furthermore, `shiny` defines some of the tags (most notably `<html>` and `<body>`) already. While this is not a dealbreaker (code gets rendered anyways, and `<html> / <body>` taga are stripped) you should remove them for clarity.

Having said that, including any type of reatcivity does the trick:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("do", "Do!"),
   htmlOutput("graph1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$graph1 <- renderUI({
      input$do
      HTML('
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>

<script>
var xyValues = [
  {x:50, y:7},
  {x:60, y:8},
  {x:70, y:8},
  {x:80, y:9},
  {x:90, y:9},
  {x:100, y:9},
  {x:110, y:10},
  {x:120, y:11},
  {x:130, y:14},
  {x:140, y:14},
  {x:150, y:15}
];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:160}}],
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>
')
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I do not really understand what you want to do, because your code is static in the moment and the whole idea of shiny is to **react** in some way or the other. That is, in this toy example I would drop the `render` part completely and put *static* code to the `UI` .

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But I still do not understand how my putting a action button the this code is rendering? I am trying to incorporate this in my Dt table . This plot will be dynamic and changes as per user filters

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am trying to do here. I am plotting the graph inside the dt table itself as per filters selected

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("do", "select", choices = c(3,4,5,6)),
  selectInput("do1", "select1", choices = c(50,100)),
  dataTableOutput("graph1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
  # a1 <- 3
  
 
  
    output$graph1 <- renderDataTable({
      df_1 <- data.frame(a = c(50, 100))
      
      df1 <-  df_1 %>% filter(a %in% input$do1) %>% mutate(b =  c(glue::glue(HTML('
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart{a}" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>

<script>
var xyValues = [
  {{x:{a}, y:{input$do}}},
  {{x:60, y:8}},
  {{x:70, y:8}},
  {{x:80, y:9}},
  {{x:90, y:9}},
  {{x:100, y:9}}
];

new Chart("myChart{a}", {{
  type: "scatter",
  data: {{
    datasets: [{{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
      data: xyValues
    }}]
  }},
  options: {{
    legend: {{display: false}},
    scales: {{
      xAxes: [{{ticks: {{min: 40, max:100}}}}],
      yAxes: [{{ticks: {{min: 1, max:16}}}}],
    }}
  }}
}});
</script>
'))))
      
      datatable(df1, escape = F,rownames = F,options = list(autowidth = FALSE))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```